# Windows SDK 7.1 Command Prompt: difference bethween /Release and /Debug environment

Tags: windows, command-line, build, sdk, development-environment

I'm trying to use SetEnv.cmd from Windows SDK 7.1 instead of vcvarsall.bat from Visual C++ 2010 Express to build 64-bit library (Qt 5.4) on command-line using `NMAKE`. `SetEnv.cmd` has `/Release` and `/Debug` options, that creates a Release or Debug build environment (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660764%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). `vcvarsall.bat` had no such options.

Question: What is the difference between release and debugging build environments in SetEnv.cmd?

Comment: `/Debug` sets the MSBuild `Configuration` environment variable to "Debug".